# Test if an XML node is blank and if so hard code href attribute value | if not blank use value for href attribute using XMSL

Tags: xml, xslt

I have XML that gets values from user input. I want to test to see if the url node is blank.

*XSLT Processor is Saxon 11.3*

**If it is blank**

- then I want to insert a value into a href

**If it is not blank**

- I want to use the node's value in the href

I have the following code but it is not working. What am I doing wrong?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<xsl:template match="unique-component-name/card">
<html>
<body>


  <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="(url = '')">
      <a href="https://example.com">
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
      <a href="{url}">
    </xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
    
    <h3><xsl:value-of select="level" /></h3>
    <h4><xsl:value-of select="name" /></h4>
    <h5><xsl:value-of select="location" /></h5>
  </a>


</body>
</html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Here is an example of my XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>


<unique-component-name>
  
  <card>
    
    <url></url>
    <level>Level Value</level>
    <name>Name Value</name>
    <location>Location Value</location>
    
  </card>
  
</unique-component-name>
```

**Expected Results in HTML**

```
    <a href="https://example.com">
     <h3>Level Value</h3>
     <h4>Name Value</h4>
     <h5>Location Value</h5>
    </a>
```

**What I'm Getting**

```
    <!-- Result with blank url node -->
    <a href="https://example.com">
       <!-- h3, h4, h5 missing -->
    </a>

    <!-- Result when url node is populated -->
    <!-- Nothing, No HTML elements -->
```

Comment: Please edit your question and add (1) a complete stylesheet, not a snippet taken out of context, and (2) the expected result - see: [mcve]. Also make sure we know which version of XST your processor supports.

Comment: XSLT Processor is Saxon 11.3

Comment: Saxon 11.3 suports XSLT 3.0 - so either one of Conal Tuohy's suggestions should work well for you. The main point here is that XSLT must be well-formed XML. That means you cannot output different start-tags within `xsl:choose` and close them using a common end-tag - as you should have seen from the error message: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/93YNgW2. IOW, XSLT works on the tree, not on the markup.

Comment: Thank you @michael.hor257k the xsltfiddle is a game changer. Are there any other XSLT fiddles that give helpful error messages as well?

Comment: Any proper testing environment should give you error messages. How are you running the transformation now?

Comment: I won't name the online software but what I was using before would only tell me that there was an error. I was not getting specific errors like the fiddle you shared shows.

Answer (score 0):

This would be a way to build an `a` element and conditionally set `href` attribute

```
<xsl:element name="a">
  <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="(url = '')">
        <xsl:attribute name="href">https://example.com</xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
      <xsl:attribute name="href"><xsl:value-of select="url"/></xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
  <h3><xsl:value-of select="level"/></h3>
  <h4><xsl:value-of select="name"/></h4>
  <h5><xsl:value-of select="location"/></h5>
</xsl:element>
```

Answer (score 0):

> I have the following code but it is not working. What am I doing wrong?

"Not working" is not a good description of a problem. You need to tell us how it fails. At this point, all we can say is that your XSLT code is not well-formed XML. You haven't closed the `a` elements. Instead of:

```
  <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="(url = '')">
      <a href="https://example.com">
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
      <a href="{url}">
    </xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
```

it needs to be:

```
  <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="(url = '')">
      <a href="https://example.com"/>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
      <a href="{url}"/>
    </xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
```

Or - if you do need to insert the headings into the anchor:

```
<a>
    <xsl:attribute name="href">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="(url = '')">https://example.com</xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:value-of select="url"/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:attribute>
    <h3>
        <xsl:value-of select="level"/>
    </h3>
    <h4>
        <xsl:value-of select="name"/>
    </h4>
    <h5>
        <xsl:value-of select="location"/>
    </h5>
</a>
```

*(note that this is XSLT 1.0-compatible syntax)*

And of course you must get rid of the orphaned `</a>` closing tag at the end.

Comment: Seems OP wants H* elements to be the text of the `a` element and that's not included in this answer.

Comment: @LMC  That's up to OP to clarify (as I asked them to do).

Comment: @LMC I just updated the post.

Answer (score 0):

You don't specify what version of XSLT you are using. In XSLT 2 and later, you could do this:

```xml
<a href="{(url[normalize-string()], 'https://example.com')[1]}">
  <h3><xsl:value-of select="level"/></h3>
  <h4><xsl:value-of select="name"/></h4>
  <h5><xsl:value-of select="location"/></h5>
</a>
```

NB the expression `(url[normalize-string()], 'https://example.com')[1]` means:

The first item from the sequence consisting of:

- the `url` element (if it's not blank), and
- the string `'https://example.com'`

If the `url` element is missing or empty, then the sequence will contain only one item; the string `'https://example.com'`; and hence that will be the first item in the sequence, and will be returned by the predicate `[1]`

This idiom `(a, b, c)[1]` is often used in XPath 2 and later; it allows you to select some data item `a`, but fall back to some other piece of data `b` if it's missing, and fall back again (to `c`) if the second alternative is also missing...

Comment: Another XSLT 2 alternative for the `a/@href` attribute value template would be: `{if (url) then url else 'https://example.com'}`